# screen tag in css showing error in netbeans?

Tags: css, netbeans, css-animations

I'm creating a sample application using netbeans having some css files in that. I'm using following tag:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    #hero{height: 480px;}
    .herocontent{padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 30px;}
}
```

This tag is showing an error as "un expected symbols found and" message.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .gridmenu {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

This tag is showing error as "un expected symbol found screen" message. Please help me to resolve these issues.

Comment: What version of netbeans are you using? -I'm on 8.0.2 and get no issues with the above - however I have come up with valid css (though more often less) that netbeans detects and marks as invalid - it's not perfect, so in some cases you do have to just ignore the warnings though the fat red icons make it really difficult. Do you get the same errors if you paste the two sections in an otherwise empty stylesheet? -If not it suggests the problem is actually *before* those blocks...

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a NetBeans bug, see this https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=177048

Answer (score 0):

Since the above code is technically correct it sounds like this is a bug in the application. Try dropping the `only screen and` and `screen and` since they are not super necessary and see if that helps! -GL